# During Eclipse debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

While debugging my code in eclipse IDE,
the code enters into some class files.
Please refer to the screen shot here,

![enter image description here][1]
http://imageshack.us/f/26/newposterh.jpg/

I get confused here.
Please tell me what is the best way to recover in this case

Comment: What exactly is your question? Is Eclipse doing something wrong, or is your code doing something wrong? What do you mean by "recover in this case"?

Comment: I mean recover means , going back to the debugging points on to source code in Eclipse

Comment: This is my code .
`
 System.out.println(objectToString(result));
 System.out.println("After the execution of Upper Method );
 System.exit(0);
`

When i press F5 at  System.out.println(objectToString(result)); 
it enters into debug mode with that screen shot .
 **
My question is how can i come back to the line **
System.out.println("After the execution of Upper Method );

Comment: Don't click - it's a picture of Rick Astley!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get `NoSuchMethodException`. It can happen only if your sources are not synchronized. Meaning during the compilation you used one class, but in runtime you have replaced it with a different version of this class. Check your classpath.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your application threw an exception.

Set some break points before the exception is thrown and attempt to determine why the exceptions was thrown.